# SQL Database Managed Instance file name change

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have SQL db on Azure, this is SQL Database Managed Instance. There are some differencees between SQL Server, one of them is that I cannot ALTER DATABASE to change file name
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server

Any tips how can I do it?
For now my only idea is to create backup, drop database, restore in on SQL Server, change file name, backup it and restore on SQL Manage Instance with correct file name.
Any idea how to do it quicker?